# Gatsby offline deployment

Tags: offline, gatsby

I am looking for a way to create a package from my gatsby page where you just open the local index.html in your browser and the page works as if it was deployed on and served by a server.

I found gatsby-plugin-offline, but as far as I understand it this does not solve my problem as it requires a server for initial loading of the page.

Is there any way to create such a package?

Comment: [Related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4610).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partially supported by Gatsby in v1, but not in Gatsby v2.

There are various workarounds, like using Electron or cordova to build an app from your site, but neither option directly solves your problem.

You could create such a plugin for Gatsby. The code required for the plugin is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer. These links should help you get started and feel free to post specific questions if you hit issues.

- https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/plugin-authoring/
- https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/